# Creating horizontal ruler with heading using bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create HR with heading and label.
It should look like:

[image]

Codepan: [CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/Emxui)

I am not good with css, I appreciate if someone can tell what components of bootstrap should I use. Or change in css

html:

```
<h3> <span>Top pics </span> <span>Popular </span> <span> Friend analysis </span> </h3></t>
<hr>
<h6>Article changes everyday, come back for more</h6>

<h3> IT should  look like this
</h3>
<img src="http://i43.tinypic.com/33tgdn8.png">
```

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com: THANKS, but I am much worried about header of hr

Comment: Can you give a link to the site where you got the screenshot from? I will help, but I don't want to code the whole thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at your screenshot and created the HTML using Bootstrap 3 and CSS. Please look at **[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ioHBt)**.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="menu col-md-8">
      <ul>
        <li>Top picks<span>beta</span></li>
        <li>Popular<span>beta</span></li>
        <li>Friends analysis</li>
        <hr>
      </ul>
      <p class="custom-alert">Article changes everyday! come back for more fun......<p>
    </div>
    </div><!--./row-->
</div><!--./container -->
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  font-size: 130%;
  color: gray;
}
hr {
    margin-top: 1%;
}
.menu > ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu > ul > li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10%;
}
.menu > ul > li:first-child {
  color: red;
}
.menu > ul > li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
.menu > ul > li > span {
  color: black;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: super;
  padding: 1%;
}
.custom-alert {
  padding-left: 7%;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hope it's self contained now!

Comment: `.menu > ul {}` controls it but I could not get how to increase the length of hr = page width

Comment: I forgot to add <hr>, apologies. I modified the code in above answer and code in demo, hope it answers your question.

Comment: just add `width: 100%;` to `<hr>` tag